# Having trouble implementing a vectorized + regularized version of logistic regressions gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression, regularized

So the formula looks like this
[image]

And my implementation looks like this

```
grad[0] = ((utils.sigmoid(X.dot(theta))-y).dot(X[:,0])).sum()
grad[1:] = ((utils.sigmoid(X.dot(theta))-y).dot(X[:,1:])).sum()
grad[1:] = grad[1:] + (lambda_*theta[1:])
grad = grad/m
```

However, the values I get are a bit off (except for grad[0] of course)..

[image]

Where did I go wrong in my code?

Comment: Mind sharing your input arrays?  Also for the second formula shouldn't you be dividing by `m` *before* you add `lambda_*theta`?

Comment: These are the input arrays: https://i.gyazo.com/784b144bb365888aa1948d4896f587c1.png
As for the formula, it shouldn't matter because 1/m is part of both terms so I can take it out and apply it at the end, but i'll try doing it before i add it just in case

Comment: @user3483203 Changed it to this and still got the same answer as when I divided it all by m : https://i.gyazo.com/0d0db41de0d14bda73fac8a234d3c261.png

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I'm an idiot haha. The second sum (in line 2) should not be there as that's 2 columns that should be added.

Also cleaned up the code a bit, but this is the right way to do it

```
h = utils.sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
grad[0] = (1/m)*((h-y).dot(X[:,0])).sum()
grad[1:] = (1/m)*((h-y).dot(X[:,1:])) + ((lambda_/m)*theta[1:])
```